# Using `require` on the variable content (not filepath)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use the content of a variable (containing string content of code), to be loaded in Node. Below is an example of target string, I want to load:

```
var codeVar = "var _ = require('lodash');\n _.each(...";
```

I read about using `Module` in `Node` which does the `require` functionality behind the scenes. I can use the `Module.wrap(<var>)` successfully, but have no luck in getting the `Module._load` or `Module._compile` working.

I need something like:

```
var code = require(codeVar);
```

Any ideas / pointers ??

Comment: Could you try to clarify? Do you mean you want to "require" a string of JS and use it like a module?

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: @micnic I get the code in `POST` on the server side and want to execute it.

Comment: You want to execute arbitrary code from a server?

Comment: So what happens when someone does `var codeVar = 'require("child_process").exec("rm -rf /")'`.

Comment: @BenFortune I know that can be unsafe. But in my particular case, the code source is trusted.

Comment: then you can use just `eval()` :D or it is formatted as a CommonJS module?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution which fits this case. Putting it here for ref:

`eval` in this case would work but also pollutes the `namespace`. `Node` has a better method of doing this, using [`vm`](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html).

So, for the above case we can have something like:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var sandbox = {
  myLocalVar: '12'
};

var context = vm.createContext(sandbox);

vm.runInContext(codeVar, context, 'myfile.vm');
```

This populates my `context` with the codeVar details and I can further use `vm.createScript` to execute code.